# org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.setBootClasspath(Ljava/lang/String;)V'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

I'm unable to build the project after updating android studio to 3.4. can anyone please help me.

```
Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.setBootClasspath(Ljava/lang/String;)V'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)

Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':LogManagerAndroidProject'.
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.wrapException(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:72)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$600(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:198)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject$1.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:111)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:25)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:200)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:186)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:95)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:693)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:141)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectAccessListener.evaluateProjectAndDiscoverTasks(DefaultProjectAccessListener.java:32)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectAccessListener.beforeResolvingProjectDependency(DefaultProjectAccessListener.java:28)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultProjectDependency.beforeResolved(DefaultProjectDependency.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.dependencies.ProjectIvyDependencyDescriptorFactory.createDependencyDescriptor(ProjectIvyDependencyDescriptorFactor
y.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.dependencies.DefaultDependencyDescriptorFactory.createDependencyDescriptor(DefaultDependencyDescriptorFactory.java
:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.dependencies.DefaultLocalConfigurationMetadataBuilder.addDependencies(DefaultLocalConfigurationMetadataBuilder.jav
a:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.dependencies.DefaultLocalConfigurationMetadataBuilder.addDependenciesAndExcludes(DefaultLocalConfigurationMetadata
Builder.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.component.local.model.DefaultLocalComponentMetadata$DefaultLocalConfigurationMetadata.realizeDependencies(DefaultLocalComponentMetadata.java:499)
        at org.gradle.internal.component.local.model.DefaultLocalComponentMetadata$DefaultLocalConfigurationMetadata.addDefinedExcludes(DefaultLocalComponentMetadata.java:456)
        at org.gradle.internal.component.local.model.DefaultLocalComponentMetadata$DefaultLocalConfigurationMetadata.getExcludes(DefaultLocalComponentMetadata.java:447)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.NodeState.getModuleResolutionFilter(NodeState.java:384)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.NodeState.visitOutgoingDependencies(NodeState.java:192)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:169)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:131)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:121)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:171)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:86)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:73)
        ... 160 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:86)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:324)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:234)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:140)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:190)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:187)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.stepEvaluationListener(DefaultProject.java:1419)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$NotifyAfterEvaluate.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:196)
        ... 196 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.setBootClasspath(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.JavaCompileConfigAction.execute(JavaCompileConfigAction.java:82)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.JavaCompileConfigAction.execute(JavaCompileConfigAction.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.create(DefaultTaskContainer.java:360)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskContainerAdaptor.create(TaskContainerAdaptor.java:59)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.AndroidTaskRegistry.create(AndroidTaskRegistry.java:47)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.AndroidTaskRegistry.create(AndroidTaskRegistry.java:89)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.createJavacTask(TaskManager.java:1124)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.LibraryTaskManager.lambda$createTasksForVariantData$9(LibraryTaskManager.java:215)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.LibraryTaskManager.createTasksForVariantData(LibraryTaskManager.java:206)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createTasksForVariantData(VariantManager.java:460)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.lambda$createAndroidTasks$1(VariantManager.java:282)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createAndroidTasks(VariantManager.java:278)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createAndroidTasks$6(BasePlugin.java:601)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:596)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$4(BasePlugin.java:526)
        at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
        at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$5(BasePlugin.java:522)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1$1.run(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:150)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.reapply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:58)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:147)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:144)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
        at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
        ... 206 more
```

Answer (score 11):

SampleProject/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
▼ change
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip

Answer (score 5):

The version of gradle  in `gradle-wrapper.properties` doesn’t match the version of Android build tools specified in the project’s `build.gradle`. Each version of Android build tools is only compatible with certain versions of Gradle, see https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle.

You can change one of them. Below is a sample:

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

**build.gradle**

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

Answer (score 4):

try to change distributionUrl in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1.20-all.zip`

Answer (score 3):

Update the classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1' to latest version in your project gradle.

Answer (score 2):

Between gradle version v4.0.0 and v5.0.0 the method "void setBootClasspath(String bootClasspath)" moved from the class **CompileOptions** to the class **MinimalJavaCompileOptions**:

```
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.MinimalJavaCompileOptions.setBootClasspath
```

Using gradle version below v5.0.0 solved the problem in my case.

Installation (for installation details look at README.md):

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch v4.4.1 https://github.com/gradle/gradle.git gradle_v4.4.1
cd gradle_v4.4.1
less README.md
```

Comment: And how do you fix it if you want to actually update Gradle?

Comment: @FranMarzoa Update the Android build tools in `build.gradle` to a version that is compatible with the new version of Gradle. See https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle for a compatibility list.

Answer (score 0):

As seen from your error:

> The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
>   Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)

Try to kill your gradle daemons using below command:

```
$ ps -ef | grep '.*GradleDaemon.*'
```

Then kill the `PID`s using `kill`, e.g.

```
$ kill -f 91747
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the file `gradle-wrapper.properties` exists at path `ProjectRoot/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

P.S. If the project is pulled from GIT, Ask the developer to add `gradle-wrapper.properties` to git by `Right-Click --> Add`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using intellij 2019, try upgrading to 2021. This worked for me.