# I am facing gradle sync error when I open the project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-developer-api

> ERROR: Unable to find method
>   'org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.setBootClasspath(Ljava/lang/String;)V'.

I tried to upgrade and downgrade the Gradle but getting the same error

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.micutu.locatedriver"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.6"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true

        }
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
}
```

Comment: show the code of how your gradle looks

Comment: code added above

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55912753/org-gradle-api-tasks-compile-compileoptions-setbootclasspathljava-lang-string

Comment: nothing works i tried this

Comment: Try this: 

in Android Studio > File > Project Structure > Project > Gradle Plugin Version  = 3.4.1 > Gradle Version = 5.1.1